# Android apt plugin is incompatible use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead

Tags: android, build.gradle, annotation-processor, android-apt

hi i'm trying to implement [imgly SDK](https://github.com/imgly/pesdk-android-demo) to my app but i get this error when i add sdk compile in Build.Gradle file .  i tried to add `annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6"` but still doesn't work

> Error:android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle
>   plugin.  Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.mutualmobile.gradle.plugins.dexinfo'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "maa.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 8
        versionName "4.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

}
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //notifications
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.6'
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6"
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.vodyasov:amr:0.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.7'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.6-android'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'ly.img.android:photo-editor-sdk:5.0.13'
    apt 'ly.img.android:build-processor:5.0.13'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: as the error suggests, this line --> `apt 'ly.img.android:build-processor:5.0.13'`is incorrect update to `annotationProcessor`, also remove : `apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`

Comment: @MarkKeen thanks so much ^^